# BLAST via Biopython NCBIWWW. Where can I find the complete database list?

Tags: biopython, blast, ncbi

I am using the module Biopython module NCBIWWW to blast some sequences online. I would like to blast my sequences against different databases available, however I cannot find a comprehensive list of them.

Here is an eample of simple query to the Nucleotide collection database using "blastn" algorithm.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", some_sequence)
```

As you can see, the database Nucleotide collection is specified as "nt".
With what shall I substitute "nt" in case I want to query the Human GRCh37/hg19 database for example? And if I want to query other species/builds? Is there any comprehensive list available where I can find the short names for all the databases available at http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By looking at biopython's documentation in the code at https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Blast/NCBIWWW.py it seems it is querying this api http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/Doc/urlapi.html

> (...) This function does no checking of the validity of the parameters
>       and passes the values to the server as is.  More help is available at:
>       http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/Doc/urlapi.html

As you can see biopython enables you to query/parse all aspects of that api including the 'DATABASE' entry. Now the problem, which is actually your matter of your question is what is the short name for your db so that is recognized by the api. The documentation of the api isn't great so they don't have there any sort of list with valid db names (which is totally biopython agnostic).

I found these lists at ebi's which although not solving the problem seems to help

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/sss/ncbiblast/help/index-nucleotide.html
http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/sss/ncbiblast/help/index-protein.html

Another approach would be to see how they name their dbs in the public ftp
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/db/

Hope this helps. Fábio

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your answer. The lists you provided are very close to what I am looking for. Unfortunately I still cannot access the databases as I would like. In the [BLAST web form] (http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__9606__9558&LINK_LOC=blasthome) for example there is the option to choose between the Human reference genome GECh37 and GRCh38. I would expect to be able to do the same using the api but I cannot find how to specify the right database/genome-build, also in the list you posted there is no indication about different builds.

Comment: @alec_djinn One slightly trickier approach is to inspect http request when you do the blast in the web. Then get to know how they make up their form data and resulting encoded url. You can do this with developer tools in Chrome. Check this example http://i.imgur.com/JGgMKWH.png?1 and let me know it you need help. My guess is their database namings should be the same and thus it would work from biopython. Fábio

Comment: Interesting! I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: @FábioMadeira You're latest comment is really helpful. Can you add it to your answer and make it extra visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=tblastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome and click on the database drop down list and you will find the database names there like, nr, nt, est etc.

Try http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&PROG_DEF=blastn&BLAST_PROG_DEF=megaBlast&BLAST_SPEC=OGP__9606__9558 for Human Genome.

Comment: Yes, but that works for some databases, what if I want the Human Genome hg19?

Comment: This works well from the website, my question is how to get the same query (Human genome GRCh37) using NCBIWWW? Which string do I need to put instead "nt" in the function call? `NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "Genome (GRCh37.p13 reference assembly top-level, Annotation Release 105) - Homo sapiens", fasta_string)` does not work...

Comment: Create a local DB by yourslef then!

Comment: I guess that the answer to my question is that there is no way --using Biopython at least-- to query BLAST in the same way it is possible to do with the web form.

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down options under "Database" in [this interface](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastp&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&BLAST_SPEC=&LINK_LOC=blasttab&LAST_PAGE=blastn) appear to provide the options for each type of BLAST. I copied the names of these options in the BLAST sections of [my Python module](https://github.com/freiburgermsu/codons#blast_protein) that uses the NCBIWWW function and accepted these options are parameters.